# No return from the Deletion function of Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search-tree

I tried to define a `delete` function for a BST, and have run into some trouble. 
There are `insert`, `find_max`, `search`, `preorder`, and `delete` functions in this `Solution` class. I expected to delete elements by using these function and test the result by deleting node = 3, 8, 21 then print the output.

However, I found that there is no output returned and the value of BS Tree are not same as I have expected, which is this expect outcome:

[image]

I wonder that this trouble might because some `None` value.

Below are the input value:

```
root = None
s = Solution()
# 放入資料
root = s.insert(root, 10)
root = s.insert(root, 21)
root = s.insert(root, 6)
root = s.insert(root, 3)
root = s.insert(root, 8)
root = s.insert(root, 19)
root = s.insert(root, 24)
root = s.insert(root, 7)
root = s.insert(root, 15)
root = s.insert(root, 22)
root = s.insert(root, 20)
root = s.insert(root, 25)

root = s.delete(root, 3)  # where root is leaf node
root = s.delete(root, 8)  # where root is left tree
root = s.delete(root, 21) # where root is BST
s.preorder(root)
```

And here is the code.

```
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution():

    def insert(self, root, val):
        ...

    def search(self, root, target):

        # Pre-Order
        if root is None:
            return None
        else:
            if target == root.val:
                return root
            elif target < root.val:
                return self.search(root.left, target)
            else:
                return self.search(root.right, target)

    def find_max(self, root):

        now = root
        while now.right:
            now = now.right
        return now

    def delete(self, root, target):

        root = self.search(root, target)

        if root is None:
            return root
        else:
            if target == root.val:
                # when root is a leaf node
                if root.left is None and root.right is None:
                    root = None
                    return root

                elif root.left is None or root.right is None:
                    # when root is a left tree
                    if root.left:
                        root = root.left
                        return root

                    # when root is a right tree
                    else:
                        root = root.right
                        return root

                # when root is a BST
                elif root.left and root.right:
                    change_value = self.find_max(root.left)
                    root.val = change_value.val
                    root.left = self.delete(self, root.left, root.val)
                    return root


            else:
                return root

    # print the value of BST
    def preorder(self, root):
        if root is not None:
            print(root.val)
            self.preorder(root.left)
            self.preorder(root.right)
```

the original BST image:

[image: Original Value]

Comment: What output do you expect? preorder does not return anything.

Comment: So what output do you see instead?

Comment: There is no output return, but it seems that the value of root is `NoneType object of bulitins module`. And I expect print output like 10→6→7→9→20→19→15→24→22→25.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone who gave me some clues! I found that the answer to the above question, and the key point is "recursive". I need to the apply recursive function in order to consider every expection; as the result, maybe I can't apply `search` function in this context.

Here is the code after I applied recursive concept and stopped using `search` function:

```
class TreeNode():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution():

    def insert(self, root, val):
        ...
    def search(self, root, target):
        # Pre-Order
        if root is None:
            return None
        else:
            if target == root.val:
                return root
            elif target < root.val:
                return self.search(root.left, target)
            else:
                return self.search(root.right, target)

    def find_max(self, root):

        now = root
        while now.right:
            now = now.right
        return now

    def delete(self, root, target):

        if root is None:
            return root
        else:
            if target < root.val:
                root.left = self.delete(root.left, target)
                return root
            elif target > root.val:
                root.right = self. delete(root.right, target)
                return root
            else:
                # where root is a leaf node
                if root.left is None and root.right is None:
                    root = None
                    return root
                if root.right is None or root.left is None:
                    # when root is a left tree
                    if root.left:
                        root = root.left
                        return root
                    # when root is a right tree
                    else:
                        root = root.right
                        return root
                # when root is a binary search tree
                elif root.left and root.right:
                    root.val = self.find_max(root.left).val
                    root.left = self.delete(root.left, root.val)
                    return root

    # print the outcome of the tree
    def preorder(self, root):
        if root is not None:
            print(root.val)
            self.preorder(root.left)
            self.preorder(root.right)


root = None
s = Solution()
root = s.insert(root, 10)
root = s.insert(root, 21)
root = s.insert(root, 6)
root = s.insert(root, 3)
root = s.insert(root, 8)
root = s.insert(root, 19)
root = s.insert(root, 24)
root = s.insert(root, 7)
root = s.insert(root, 15)
root = s.insert(root, 22)
root = s.insert(root, 20)
root = s.insert(root, 25)

# s.preorder(root)
```

Finally, it seems that it return correct output.

```
10
6
3
8
7
20
19
15
24
22
25
```

Any advice is welcome! Or if there is still possible to apply `search` function to finish this attempt, please give me some suggestions or hints!!